# Writing our own Dispose method instead of using Idisposable

Tags: c#, idisposable

After going through a lot of articles on `IDisposable`, I got confused about its usage. All the articles explain what is it and how to implement it, but I want to understand what we will miss if we don't have it.

Here is an example of an class implementing `IDisposable`. Often the use of dispose is shown as disposing a **database connection.**

```
public class Test : IDisposable
{
    public Test()
    {
        DatabaseConnection databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.databaseConnection != null)
        {
            this.databaseConnection.Dispose();
            this.databaseConnection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Although `Dispose()` is implemented, inside the `Dispose()` method, the dispose property of `databaseConnection` is used to free the connection (`this.databaseConnection.Dispose();`).

My question is **why do we need to implement `IDisposable` in this case?** We can directly call `this.databaseConnection.Dispose()` and free the connection. Why implement `IDisposable` when internally it also calls the `Dispose()` method of the object?

Alternative to the approach of `IDisposable`, we can implement a method `Release()` to free the memory.

```
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        DatabaseConnection databaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection();
    }

    public void Release()
    {
        if (this.databaseConnection != null)
        {
            this.databaseConnection.Dispose();
            this.databaseConnection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the difference between these two approaches? Do we really need `IDisposable`? I am looking forward to a concrete explanation.

Comment: The code is quite wrong, it needs to be a private member of the class, not a local variable of the constructor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right, using your Release method you would get the exact same effect, provided you always remember to call it.

The reason why you should use `Dispose` / `IDisposable` for this sort of thing is consistency. All .NET developers will know about the IDisposable pattern, and a class being IDisposable indicates that you *should* dispose of it, and do it using the Dispose method. In other words, using the IDisposable pattern immediately tells another developer, that he should release the resources held by the class, and he should do it by calling the `Dispose` method.

Another benefit of implementing `IDisposable` is the using block, which works on any IDisposable class:

```
using(var t = new Test())
{
    // use t
}
```

Using the above code will result in `t` being `Dispose()`ed at the end of the `using` block. It is syntactic sugar for a `try`...`finally` block, but it tends to make this kind of code more concise and easier to read and write.

Comment: apart from consistency do you see any other motivating factor to use Idisposable

Comment: @Piyush - Not allowing the client programmer to use a keyword in the language is rather a big deal that goes well beyond consistency.

Comment: I would say that a fundamental parts of the .NET object contract, which objects should attempt to obey to the fullest extent possible, is that object cleanup prior to abandonment should not require any action other than calling `IDisposable.Dispose` [for classes which don't implement `IDisposable`, no action should be required].  Even though `IDisposable` is an interface, it should be thought of more as part of the `Object` contract, especially since the fact that a concrete class *didn't* implement `IDisposable` would more about the class than the fact that it *did*.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your `Release()` worked correctly (it doesn't, but that's a different matter), then people would have to learn about it, and learn something else with another class, and so on.
2. Your `Release()` could never be found programatically. It's possible to programatically call `Dispose()` when applicable with:

   ```
   if(obj is IDisposable)
     ((IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
   ```

While not often done, when it is done, it's vital.

It is sometimes useful to have a method like your `Release()` when it's possible someone might want to call it during object use. An example of this is `Close()` on `Stream`. Note here though that `Stream.Dispose()` still exists, and calls into `Close()`.

Answer (score 1):

`IDisposable` is worth implementing, mostly, because it's idomatic in C#.  Everybody knows what `IDisposable` does, and how to deal with an object that implements `IDisposable`.  When you are releasing resources using something other than `IDisposable.Dispose()`, you're deviating from the generally-understood idiom.

This means that a maintainer doesn't have to know the ins and outs of your particular class to prevent leaking resources.  This may even be you, in 6 months, when you've forgotten most of what you've done with this piece of code!  All you need to know is that it implements `IDisposable`, which has a commonly-understood meaning.

Remember that `IDisposable`, mostly, is a signal to a developer, "Hey, I'm a class that holds references to unmanaged resources.  You probably shouldn't wait on the garbage collector to clean me up."  Note that this may be indirectly via composition (a class that implements `IDisposable` because it has private members that implement `IDisposable`).  When a decent C# developer sees a class implementing `IDisposable`, they should immediately think "This object is special, and needs to be cleaned up when I'm done with it."  There's nothing preventing you from writing a `Release()` method; it just means that you're more likely to accidentally leak resources because you're not using the idiomatic pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DotNetTips
{
    private void DoSomeOperation()
    {
        using (var con1 = new SqlConnection("First Connection String"),
                   con2 = new SqlConnection("Second Connection String"))
        {
            // Rest of the code goes here
        }
    }

    private void DoSomeOtherOperation()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            // Rest of the code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

A `using` statement is useful when we have to call the `Dispose()` method multiple times on different objects. Otherwise, we will have to call it on each object as:

```
if (con != null) con.Dispose();
if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed objects will be disposed of automatically by garbage collection at some non-deterministic point in the future.  However, when working with objects that may hold unmanaged resources (not under control of the CLR / garbage collection), the `IDisposable` interface should be implemented to provide a consistent and deterministic method of returning these resources to the operating system.

The interface only provides any real benefit when the object is used within the context of a `using() { ... }` block.  Such a block tells the CLR to call the `Dispose` method when it hits the closing brace of the block.  So no matter what happens within this block (short of some catastrophic system failure), your `Dispose` method is guaranteed to be called and your unmanaged resources freed.

For instance, in the code you provided, if an exception was thrown, then your `Release()` method may never get called, potentially leaving the connection open.  However, when working with a disposable object within a `using` block, when the exception is thrown, the CLR will jump in and call your `Dispose` method before it throws the exception.